# Async ignored on AJAX requests on Nginx server

Tags: nginx

Despite sending an async request to the server over AJAX, the server will not respond until the previous unrelated request has finished. The following code is only broken in this way on Nginx, but runs perfectly on Apache.

This call will start a background process and it waits for it to complete so it can display the final result.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    url: $(this).data('route'),
    data: $('input[name=data]').val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { /* do stuff */}
    error: function (data) { /* handle errors */}
});
```

The below is called after the above, which on Apache requires 100ms to execute and repeats itself, showing progress for data being written in the background:

```
checkStatusInterval = setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        url: '/process-status?process=' + currentElement.attr('id'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { /* update progress bar and status message */ }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Unfortunately, when this script is run from nginx, the above progress request never even finishes a single request until the first AJAX request that sent the data is done. If I change the async to TRUE in the above, it executes one every interval, but none of them complete until that very first AJAX request finishes.

Here is the main nginx conf file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    # configure temporary paths
    # nginx is started with param -p, setting nginx path to serverpack installdir
    fastcgi_temp_path temp/fastcgi;
    uwsgi_temp_path temp/uwsgi;
    scgi_temp_path temp/scgi;
    client_body_temp_path temp/client-body 1 2;
    proxy_temp_path temp/proxy;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    # Sendfile copies data between one FD and other from within the kernel.
    # More efficient than read() + write(), since the requires transferring data to and from the user space.
    sendfile on;

    # Tcp_nopush causes nginx to attempt to send its HTTP response head in one packet,
    # instead of using partial frames. This is useful for prepending headers before calling sendfile,
    # or for throughput optimization.
    tcp_nopush on;

    # don't buffer data-sends (disable Nagle algorithm). Good for sending frequent small bursts of data in real time.
    tcp_nodelay on;

    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    # Timeout for keep-alive connections. Server will close connections after this time.
    keepalive_timeout 90;

    # Number of requests a client can make over the keep-alive connection. This is set high for testing.
    keepalive_requests 100000;

    # allow the server to close the connection after a client stops responding. Frees up socket-associated memory.
    reset_timedout_connection on;

    # send the client a "request timed out" if the body is not loaded by this time. Default 60.
    client_header_timeout   20;
    client_body_timeout 60;

    # If the client stops reading data, free up the stale client connection after this much time. Default 60.
    send_timeout 60;

    # Size Limits
    client_body_buffer_size   64k;
    client_header_buffer_size 4k;
    client_max_body_size      8M;

    # FastCGI
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 120;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300; # default: 60 secs; when step debugging with XDEBUG, you need to increase this value
    fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 64k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 128k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 128k;

    # Caches information about open FDs, freqently accessed files.
    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

    # Turn on gzip output compression to save bandwidth.
    # http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule
    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    #gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

    # show all files and folders
    autoindex on;

    server {
        # access from localhost only
        listen       127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         www;

        # the following default "catch-all" configuration, allows access to the server from outside.
        # please ensure your firewall allows access to tcp/port 80. check your "skype" config.
        # listen       80;
        # server_name  _;

        log_not_found off;
        charset utf-8;

        access_log  logs/access.log  main;

        # handle files in the root path /www
        location / {
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   www;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9100
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files      $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9100;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # add expire headers
        location ~* ^.+.(gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|flv|swf|pdf|mp3|mp4|xml|txt|js|css)$ {
            expires 30d;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files (if Apache's document root concurs with nginx's one)
        # deny access to git & svn repositories
        location ~ /(\.ht|\.git|\.svn) {
            deny  all;
        }
    }

    # include config files of "enabled" domains
    include domains-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

Here is the enabled domain conf file:

```
access_log  off;
access_log  C:/server/www/test.dev/logs/access.log;
error_log   C:/server/www/test.dev/logs/error.log;

# HTTP Server
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name test.dev;
    root        C:/server/www/test.dev/public;
    index       index.php;
    rewrite_log on;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;
    #include    /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    # Include common configurations.
    include     domains-common/location.conf;
}

# HTTPS server
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name test.dev;
    root        C:/server/www/test.dev/public;
    index       index.php;
    rewrite_log on;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;
    #include    /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    # Include common configurations.
    include     domains-common/location.conf;
    include     domains-common/ssl.conf;
}
```

Contents of ssl.conf:

```
# OpenSSL for HTTPS connections.
ssl                  on;
ssl_certificate      C:/server/bin/openssl/certs/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  C:/server/bin/openssl/certs/cert.key;
ssl_session_timeout  5m;
ssl_protocols              SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers                HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

# Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9100
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files      $uri =404;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9100;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Contents of location.conf:

```
# Remove trailing slash to please Laravel routing system.
if (!-d $request_filename) {
    rewrite  ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

# We don't need .ht files with nginx.
location ~ /(\.ht|\.git|\.svn) {
    deny  all;
}

# Added cache headers for images.
location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
    expires 30d;
    log_not_found off;
}

# Only 3 hours on CSS/JS to allow me to roll out fixes during early weeks.
location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
    expires 3h;
    log_not_found off;
}

# Add expire headers.
location ~* ^.+.(gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|flv|swf|pdf|mp3|mp4|xml|txt)$ {
    expires 30d;
}

# Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9100
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9100;
}
```

Any ideas where this is going wrong?

Comment: Probably running it on Windows is the problem.

Comment: `async` in ajax means that the script running in the web browser will continue to run instead of locking up until the response comes back.  `async` has nothing to do with the server.  As for the server's behavior, I suspect some sort of issue with KeepAlive and/or [request pipelining](https://www.igvita.com/2011/10/04/optimizing-http-keep-alive-and-pipelining/) but I don't have experience with nginx+fastcgi (with or without windows) to tell you what is wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Trust me, if I could afford to switch to a Mac right now......

Comment: Who said anything about Mac? The production server will almost certainly be Linux, so that's almost certainly what your development server should be.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Closest thing to Linux I'd want to run development work from.

Comment: @DerfK The browser side is clearly performing correctly. Just can't figure out what is mucking things up with the server configuration.

Comment: You must have gotten burned by Ubuntu or something. Feel free to drop into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) if you want to explore other options for a usable Linux workstation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it is *definitely* the fact that you're running nginx on Windows.

It has some [serious limitations](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html), chief among them that it uses [`select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for connection processing, and only runs a single thread in a single process. This means that, while it technically can `accept()` 1024 simultaneous connections, it can only do actual work for one request at a time.

In your case this means Windows is absolutely positively inappropriate as a development platform.

Your best bet, if you really want to continue running Windows, is to run the nginx server in a Linux virtual machine. You should also consider the advantages of running a Linux workstation.

Comment: Crap. Not the answer I was hoping for but appears to be the right answer. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get an Oracle virtualbox to run on any of my Windows systems anymore and the one good installation I had mysteriously broke the database last week. Was hoping that running nginx from Windows was a viable alternative. :(

Comment: As professional sysadmins, we also have a great deal of disdain for VirtualBox. I'm starting to think your whole development environment needs an extreme makeover...

Comment: Then what is your recommendation for a Linux virtual machine I can run on my Windows development environment?

Comment: Probably best to discuss that in chat. :)

Comment: Ya know, I tried the chat, and I can't type a single thing in the chat box to send. Chrome apparently doesn't like the chat page right now. :(

Comment: Perfect answer. thanks

Answer (score -1):

*

> It has some [serious limitations][1], chief among them that it uses
>   [`select()`][2] for connection processing, and only runs a single
>   thread in a single process. This means that, while it technically can
>   `accept()` 1024 simultaneous connections, it can only do actual work
>   for one request at a time.

*

If you repeat it often enough you start to believe this nonsense, select is non-blocking and can handle millions of concurrent connections, the problem here is a blocking scripts/module/system inside nginx which is general for all OS's, if it blocks it will block the whole worker until its done, this needs to be rewritten using cosockets.
ea.: http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,246165,246165#msg-246165

edit 18.57:
Just had a look at the config, sendfile off; to start with, it looks like you are passing and getting data from PHP, it is PHP in this way which can only process one request at the time, nginx just waits for php. If you look on the site below this answer have a look at the example conf, also look at the installer which generates a pool of php handlers for you so you can handle more concurrent requests. If this is all about sql then look at ngxLuaDB which has a working non blocking sql example in pure Lua, for speed this approach is recommended.

Comment: That doesn't appear to have any relevance. If you're going to make a claim like this, back it up with some actual evidence and a good explanation.

Comment: That is quite easy, see http://nginx-win.ecsds.eu/ a redeveloped version which does not block, period. 2nd: there is a hint in there "This call will start a background process and it waits for it to complete so it can display the final result" which clearly indicates the blocking effect, Apache just spawns a new child, nginx works differently where blocking is easy to get and also easy to solve, see also ngxLuaDB on same site explaining blocking and showing a non-blocking example using cosockets.

Comment: Installed this module according to the instructions in `nginx 1.7.5.2 WhiteRabbit` to replace my binary from `WPN-XM` along with the Lua DLL. Used the conf values from `nginx-win.conf`. However, I still can't get multiple asynchronous server connections to work. What could I be missing?

Comment: Just noticed your edit. Will try to figure that part out.